# PHP Curl not working for port 8080

Tags: php, tomcat, curl

I'm trying to send API request to APACHE tomcat server on port 8080 but it fails. I tried every possible solution but somehow it is not working.

I searched everywhere wikipedia, google, stackoverflow and other sites but no luck. Curl is able to send/receive network requests to/from same server on port 80 but fails on 8080.

When I open the same URL from browser, It just works fine but fails when sent request from server.

If somebody wants to perform tests on their own end, here is the server info

- IP Address: 122.248.246.104
- PORT: 8080

Also when I tested this from localhost (XAMPP), it worked fine.

It'd be great, if someone could help me from recovering this problem.

Regards,
Sam

Comment: I can see the tomcat output from that URL with `curl -v 122.248.246.104:8080`

Comment: It is not working via online PHP web server. It is working on local perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Operating under the assumption that you're attempting to connect from a shared server, connections via any port other than the standard 80 or 990 are disabled for security reasons.  I'd call your hosting provider and see if there's anything that they can do to enable connection via this port for your account.